# getting error UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. in express js api

Tags: node.js, angular, express, node-modules

I am working on express js api with jwtr,when i run the api it gives me error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Can't set headers after they
>   are sent.

can anyone please help me why i am getting this error, here i  have added my code, can anyone please look in it, and help me to resolve this issue,

```
const requireAuthentication = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiIxUWpuTDBhd2lTIiwiaWF0IjoxNTY5OTQwMjgyfQ.1xwX2OULW4RjKW4Ok13mwlJE8k95u-d0o7T6k5U9tjs'; //req.headers['vrc-access-token'];
        if (!token) return res.status(401).send('Failed to authenticate token.');
        let verify_token_data = await jwtr.verify(token, secret);
        if(typeof verify_token_data.jti != 'undefined') {
            req.body.username = verify_token_data.username;
            req.body.organization = verify_token_data.organization;
            req.body.userId = verify_token_data.id;
            req.body.organizationId = verify_token_data.organizationId;

            console.log("sdsd234");
            // create a new token
            const newToken = await jwtr.sign({
                username: verify_token_data.username,
                organization: verify_token_data.organization,
                id: verify_token_data.id,
                organizationId: verify_token_data.organizationId
            }, config['token-secret']);

            console.log(newToken);
            req.refreshToken = newToken;
            console.log('sdfdf');
            return await next();
        } else {
            return res.status(401).send('Failed to authenticate token.');
        }
    }  catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).send(error.message);
    }   
};
```

Answer (score 0):

i have had this issue before and it happens because you have already send the response back to the server and it reaches a code which sends a response again.

i think that the issue is when you do 
`return await next()`

what you should do is:
`next()`

```
const requireAuthentication = async(req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiIxUWpuTDBhd2lTIiwiaWF0IjoxNTY5OTQwMjgyfQ.1xwX2OULW4RjKW4Ok13mwlJE8k95u-d0o7T6k5U9tjs'; //req.headers['vrc-access-token'];
        if (!token) return res.status(401).send('Failed to authenticate token.');
        let verify_token_data = await jwtr.verify(token, secret);
        if(typeof verify_token_data.jti != 'undefined') {
            req.body.username = verify_token_data.username;
            req.body.organization = verify_token_data.organization;
            req.body.userId = verify_token_data.id;
            req.body.organizationId = verify_token_data.organizationId;

            // create a new token
            const newToken = await jwtr.sign({
                username: verify_token_data.username,
                organization: verify_token_data.organization,
                id: verify_token_data.id,
                organizationId: verify_token_data.organizationId
            }, config['token-secret']);

            console.log(newToken);
            req.refreshToken = newToken;
            next();
        } else {
            return res.status(401).send('Failed to authenticate token.');
        }
    }  catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).send(error.message);
    }   
};
```